# looking for a keyboard API

Tags: c++, api, keyboard

looking for a library for accessing the keyboards functions, key states, etc. the language I'm planning on using is C++

Comment: On what OS? This dramatically affects the possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such possibility in C++ standard. It depends on platform you are going to support. The only portable way is to use portable library.

You could try [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) library, which is good looking and pretty convenient. For console application you could try [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html).

Comment: PDCurses works on win32 and X11 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows than you'll be using various window messages like `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_KEYUP`, `WM_SYSCOMMAND`. Between those you should be able to whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try SDL: [http://www.libsdl.org](http://www.libsdl.org/).  It's cross-platform, and you don't have to use the graphics portion of the library if you don't need it.  Also, it gives you access to joysticks, if you want to have some fun ;)

Comment: i tried and its not working. simply doesn't see that a key was pressed

Comment: Look at the tutorial here: http://gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Keyboard_Input_using_an_Event_Loop